# PHP File Upload Bandwidth

Tags: php, iis

I have a page that uploads a file to my server, where it then gets copied to a permanent directory via move_uploaded_file. This all seems to work great, with the exception that in a real-life scenario I will be expecting much larger files than I have successfully sent up.

I have already tacked the timeout for the file upload by changing the connection timeout in my site settings in IIS - so the file continues to upload up to six hours ( -_- ) - but this is where I run into my current problem - It might just take six hours!

After getting the upload process to get past 10% or so ( on a 300 meg file ), I noticed that the file continues to push up, but my upload rate seems to be 'falling off' - as in, I observed faster speeds when I started the transfer, than I am seeing halfway through it. The numbers here aren't necessarily relevant, as I know that my upload ( while Im uploading, still 2 Mbps ) is capable of pushing faster than it is, and the server on the other end is on fiber.

I wonder if anyone has encountered this before, and if so, have you determined a work-around. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http is not a protocol designed for file uploads, ftp is (even has file in its name)

Comment: That's not much of an answer. FTP is what I'm trying to work away from here. Rather than handing out FTP users and passwords to my whole organization, and then having to fill everyone into the loop every time they get changed, and having to have FTP installed on 40 computers - I am migrating to an HTTP upload method. I'm well aware that the industry standard would be to use FTP, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: well if you leave out the basic information, i can but guess.

Comment: What is the context here? Perhaps a shared watch folder with rsync etc would be a better solution. If I were in your organization and I had the restart a six hour upload that reached 95% completion because my ISP reset my connection, I might be tempted to introduce my monitor to my window.

Comment: How large is the drop-off speed? If you start at `X mb/sec`, what fraction of `X` are you at after 10 minute/1 hour/etc?

Comment: Well, you're trading easyness-of-use for effective file handling. Bad deal for me as you can create a better user interface keeping the effective background

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using HTTP for this task. You may have observed that all the "file locker" services (and others which involve uploading files, such as Apple's online-music service) provide you with an "uploader" program rather than making use of the browser. There are reasons for this.

First off, the overhead of the transfer encoding is large. You take your (presumably binary) data, and Base64 encode it; that's 33% overhead. So if it would take four hours with HTTP, it would only take three with a binary protocol - and that's disregarding the chunked-transfer overhead, so the reality is probably more severe.

Second, there's no way to "resume" an upload in HTTP. So if your connection is broken, you'll either have to write application-specific code to handle the resumption, or start all over.

Third, HTTP servers are not designed for super-long-lived connections: they usually have a finite or small pool of workers to service the (usually seconds-long at the outset) client requests, and occasionally they have smallish limits on the size of request data (2GB is common, and PHP by default has only a few MB).

I strongly recommend using a *file transfer* protocol to transfer files (such as FTP). You don't have to give out a single username/password pair to everyone: you can have a gatekeeper which integrates with whatever authentication system you already have in place. FTP-over-TLS also exists and is relatively mature.

There is a fairly good summary of the differences between the two protocols [here](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html). Note that you gain nothing from any of the advantages of HTTP listed, due to your circumstances.

Don't feel limited to FTP - rsync is a great protocol for transferring files as well, especially if you only change part of the file (it even does binary deltas!). git can also efficiently transport large blobs over secure connections or even HTTP, if you insist on using that.